# Enqueue liquidsoap request from script instead of command

Tags: liquidsoap

I'm trying to write my very first liquidsoap program. It goes something like this:

```
sounds_path = "../var/sounds"

# Log file
set("log.file.path","var/log/liquidsoap.log")
set("harbor.bind_addr", "127.0.0.1")
set("harbor.timeout", 5)
set("harbor.verbose", true)
set("harbor.reverse_dns", false)

silence = blank()
queue = request.queue()

def play(~protocol, ~data, ~headers, uri) =
    request.push("#{sounds_path}#{uri}")
    http_response(protocol=protocol, code=20000)
end

harbor.http.register(port=8080, method="POST", "^/(?!\0)+", play)

stream = fallback(track_sensitive=false, [queue, silence])
...output.whatever...
```

And I was wondering if there is any way to push to the queue from the harbor callback.

Else, how should I proceed about making requests originate from HTTP calls? I really want to avoid telnet. My final objective is having an endpoint that I can call to make my stream play a file on demand and be silent the rest of the time.

Answer (score 2):

give this a go its liquidsoap so its tricky to understand but it should do the trick

```
########### functions ##############
def playnow(source,~action="override", ~protocol, ~data, ~headers, uri) =
      queue_count = list.length(server.execute("playnow.primary_queue"))
      arr = of_json(default=[("key","value")], data)  
      track = arr["track"];
      log("adding playnow track '#{track}'")

      if queue_count != 0 and action == "override" then
        server.execute("playnow.insert 0 #{track}")
        source.skip(source)
        print("skipping playnow queue")
      else
        server.execute("playnow.push #{track}")
        print("no skip required")
      end

      http_response(
        protocol=protocol,
        code=200,
        headers=[("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8")],
        data='{"status":"success", "track": "#{track}", "action": "#{action}"}'
      )
end
######## live stuff below #######

playlist= playlist(reload=1, reload_mode="watch", "/etc/liquidsoap/playlist.xspf")

requested = crossfade(request.equeue(id="playnow"))

live= fallback(track_sensitive=false,transitions=[crossfade, crossfade],[requested,  playlist])

output.harbor(%mp3,id="live",mount="live_radio", radio)

harbor.http.register(port=MY_HARBOR_PORT, method="POST","/playnow", playnow(live))
```

to use the above you need to send a post request with json data like so:
{"track":"http://mydomain/mysong.mp3"}

this is also with the assumption you have the harbor running which you should be able to find out using the liquidsoap docs

Comment: I will try this and come back with the results. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple methods of sending into the queue, there is telnet, you can create a http input, or a metadata request to playnow via the harbor, let me know which one you opt for and i can provide you with a code example

Comment: I'd like to be able to enqueue files via HTTP request on demand. I've seen the example given on HTTP input on the docs but it queries an external URI to check what's next. What I cannot seem to do is make a call to a liquidsoap endpoint with a filename included in the request (something like `/play/{filename}`) and have liquidsoap enqueue that file. Do you know how could this be accomplished?